# Getting a ClassCastException when running a Map Reduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, accumulo

I have a map reduce job that takes data from an Accumulo Table, performs an operation and then stores the result in another Accumulo Table. I have the following mapper, combiner and reducer.

```
class PivotTableMapper extends Mapper<Key, Value, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    public void map(Key k, Value v, Context context) {
        // Doing something here...
        context.write(Text Text);
    }
}

class PivotTableCombiner extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<Text> v, Context context) {
         // Doing something here....
         context.write(Text, Text);
    } 
}

class PivotTableReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Mutation> {
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text k, Iterable<Text> v, Context context) {
        // Doing something here....
        context.write(null, Mutation);
    }
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) {
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    job.setInputFormatClass(AccumuloInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(AccumuloOutputFormat.class);
    // Some additional settings
}
```

When I run the job, I get a ClassCastException

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Mutation
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat$AccumuloRecordWriter.write(AccumuloOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at com.latize.ulysses.accumulo.postprocess.PivotTable$PivotTableMapper.map(PivotTable.java:48)
        at com.latize.ulysses.accumulo.postprocess.PivotTable$PivotTableMapper.map(PivotTable.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

16/01/18 16:16:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 33% reduce 0%
16/01/18 16:16:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1453096833928_0021_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Mutation
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat$AccumuloRecordWriter.write(AccumuloOutputFormat.java:409)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
        at com.latize.ulysses.accumulo.postprocess.PivotTable$PivotTableMapper.map(PivotTable.java:48)
        at com.latize.ulysses.accumulo.postprocess.PivotTable$PivotTableMapper.map(PivotTable.java:1)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Aren't the class combinations correct?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you do not need a Reducer when using the AccumuloOutputFormat (as Accumulo itself acts like a Reducer would). Your Mapper would take  and output .

For your specific case, your Mappers need to write  which would then be sorted/reduced by your actual reducers. Change the output key and value parameterization for your Mapper.

Comment: Related question, with reference to the API calls to set the class types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331283/hadoop-mapper-and-reducer-output-mismatch